# issue with XML encoding

Tags: c#, character-encoding

I tried to phrase this as a generic question but realized I don't know enough, so here is the problem I'm having.

Here is a snippet from a console application:

```
public void Run()
{
    Run(Console.Out);
}

public void Run(TextWriter writer)
{
    DataTable customers = _quickBooksAdapter.GetTableData("Customer");
    customers.WriteXml(writer);
}
```

Then I run it from the console and use ">" to put it in a file.

```
c:\> QuickBooksETL extract US > qb_us.xml
```

If i try to load the result as I would normally:

```
var x = XDocument.Load("qb_us.xml");
```

I get the error:

```
Invalid character in the given encoding. Line 8, position 26.
```

So I tried to determine what .NET "thinks" it is using:

```
string path = @"\\ad1\accounting$\Xml\qb_us.xml"; 
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path);
sr.CurrentEncoding.Dump();
```

Result:

```
System.Text.UTF8Encoding 
BodyName utf-8
EncodingName Unicode (UTF-8)
HeaderName utf-8
WebName utf-8
WindowsCodePage 1200
IsBrowserDisplay True
IsBrowserSave True
IsMailNewsDisplay True
IsMailNewsSave True
IsSingleByte False
EncoderFallback 5EncoderReplacementFallback  
System.Text.EncoderReplacementFallback 
DefaultString �
MaxCharCount 1
DecoderFallback 5DecoderReplacementFallback  
System.Text.DecoderReplacementFallback 
DefaultString �
MaxCharCount 1
IsReadOnly True
CodePage 65001
```

Finally, I find by guessing that it works if I just explicitly say it's ASCII:

```
string path = @"\\ad1\accounting$\Xml\qb_us.xml"; 
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path, Encoding.ASCII);
var x = XDocument.Load(sr);
```

Any thoughts on where am I going wrong would be greatly appreciated.  I admit I have never taken the "deep dive" on character encodings, but I'm willing to put in the effort to get this right.

Comment: What character is at line 8, position 26?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is *not* to get the console involved. Write directly to the file from your code:

```
public void Run(string filename)
{
    DataTable customers = _quickBooksAdapter.GetTableData("Customer");
    customers.WriteXml(filename);
}
```

or create the `TextWriter` or `Stream` yourself and pass that in, e.g.

```
public void Run(Stream output)
{
    DataTable customers = _quickBooksAdapter.GetTableData("Customer");
    customers.WriteXml(output);
}
```

Note that by reading it as ASCII, you'll basically be getting question marks for any non-ASCII character in the original data. IIRC, that's the default behaviour of an encoding when it encounters binary data it can't handle.

Using a `Stream` it should default to writing out in UTF-8, and the XML declaration and the data within the file should match.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, if your data includes illegal characters (for example, character 12), the XML doesn't round trip unless you read the XML with an `XmlTextReader` with `Normalization = false`.  I've been using `XmlSerializer.Deserialize()`, not `XDocument.Load()`.  Still, you might try calling the `Load(XmlReader)` overload by passing in an `XmlTextReader` with `Normalization = false`.

I would add my voice to Jon's in suggesting that you write to your own stream, not `Console.Out`.